# What is wrong in my c program to reverse the order of the vowels in a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    system("clear");
    char* s = "education";
    int l = strlen(s);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++) 
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u' 
         || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'U') 
        {
            for (j = l - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (s[j] == 'a' || s[j] == 'e' || s[j] == 'i' || s[j] == 'o' || s[j] == 'u' 
                 || s[j] == 'A' || s[j] == 'E' || s[j] == 'O' || s[j] == 'I' || s[j] == 'U') 
                {
                    printf("%c", s[j]);
                    l = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]);
        }
    }

    free(s);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

the program is to print a given string with its vowels reversed in the order .. suppose the string is "hello".. the output will be "holle" .
the program should give an output "odicatuen".. but it shows only upto "odica".. how can i solve the issue?? what correction needed in my program?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=l;i++)` --> `for(i=0;i<l;i++)`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you really should implement and use an `isvowel`  function; your code will greatly gain in readability.

Comment: ___DO NOT edit a question to remove the mistakes pointed out in an answer, it renders the answer invalid.___

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `l = j` as soon as you replace your vowel. This reduces the "known length" of your string and as soon as you hit the middle your `l` is smaller than your iterator of the outer loop `i`. So you exit the loop

You have to add another variable to track your progress in the inner loop instead of using the length of the string for that.

Also you should let for-loops count to below the length of arrays because c arrays start at 0.

```
int l1 = l;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
{
    if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u' 
     || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'U') 
    {
        for (j = l1 - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (s[j] == 'a' || s[j] == 'e' || s[j] == 'i' || s[j] == 'o' || s[j] == 'u' 
             || s[j] == 'A' || s[j] == 'E' || s[j] == 'O' || s[j] == 'I' || s[j] == 'U') 
            {
                printf("%c", s[j]);
                l1 = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}
```

As Sourav mentioned in his answer `free()`ing a string literal provokes UB and thus should not be done.

Comment: @ArijitKarali Upvote and mark as answer instead of saying thanks is the common thing to do here.

Answer (score 4):

There are two mistakes I can notice,

1. `for(i=0;i<=l;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<l;i++)`. C arrays use 0-based indexing, so with your version of code, you'll be off-by-one.
2. You don't do `free(s)` here, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `s` is not a pointer returned by a memory allocator function.

That said, I don't get your logic, you never considered inputs having more than two vowels. In your case, as soon as you've hit the other vowel (counting from the rear side), you're doing `l = j;` which sets the outer loop limit to the position of the other vowel found and thus you get that truncated output.

Comment: i used i<l; & removed free(s) though program doesn't work .. still giving outout "odica"

Comment: Sourav maybe didn't see the `l = j` in the middle, I only saw it after the reformatting.... Still his points are both valid and a mayor problem.

Comment: Mhh the added part is not correct, he sets `l` to the next vowel from then end of the string.And the start the next iteration from there. That's what caused the problem that he ends the string in the middle

Comment: @KamiKaze Altered the wording to avoid confusion. Thanks

Comment: @SouravGhosh No Problem. Is something wrong with my answer though? As it gets ignored somehow and you get the upvotes? I edited it to improve my wording, now maybe that helps.

Comment: @KamiKaze Maybe I was the FGITW? You're answer is accepted, so don't worry, nothing's wrong there. :)